# Print count number of unique pattern occurences after each occurence

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, sort, uniq

Supposing I have a log file containing thrown Exceptions:

```
ExceptionA
loggedFunctionCall
ExceptionB
ExceptionA
loggedFunctionCall
ExceptionD
ExceptionB
loggedFunctionCall
ExceptionB
```

I want to count the number of occurrences of every different Exception and currently my solution is:

`cat file.txt | grep Exception | sort | uniq -c | sort -n`

With the result:

```
      1 ExceptionD
      2 ExceptionA
      3 ExceptionB
```

However I would like to display count number on the right side and get rid of these indents, so the final effect should look as follows:

```
ExceptionD 1
ExceptionA 2
ExceptionB 3
```

I'm looking for a simple solution - preferably without writing any additional bash scripts, just by using pure terminal commands.

Comment: suffix `| perl -pe 's/^\s+(\d+) (.*)/\2 \1/'` to your current pipeline seems to work

Answer (score 9):

You could use a simple awk command for the whole task:

```
awk '/Exception/{a[$0]++} END {for (x in a) print x,a[x]}' file | sort -nk2
```

Output

```
ExceptionD 1
ExceptionA 2
ExceptionB 3
```

The order for an `awk` associative array is undefined, so usually you will need to pipe to `sort`, `k2` means sorting by second field.

---

Another alternative for sorting is using GNU `awk` [predifined sorting](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html) and sort by numerical value, ascending:

```
awk '/Exception/{a[$0]++} END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"
        for (x in a) print x,a[x]
    }' file
```

---

Also, if you want to keep your existing commands, and to just reverse the position of the two fields, you can modify to:

```
grep 'Exception' file | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2,$1}' | sort -nk2
```

Comment: Note that `awk '{print $2,$1}'` only works as long as the matched expressions contain no space.

Comment: Yes, this is the case in the example. I noticed you think of the generalization, to print the last field first and the rest of the line following, which could have many good ideas for awk,sed,cut,etc...

Comment: Indeed, I had proposed `awk '{$(NF+1)=$1;$1=""}1'`, but that mangles spaces. Doing it all in one Awk as you suggest is the most appropriate.

Comment: I do wish awk came with more array functionality. perl's handy here: `| perl -lane 'push @F, shift @F; print join " ", @F'`

Comment: @glennjackman the problem is you could say that about 100 different things and then you end up with a language that has thousands of constructs/operations instead of one with 20 or so and that leads to https://www.zoitz.com/comics/perl_small.png. If people want a language with all those constructs they already have one. Despite the occasional frustration I've **really** come to appreciate the awk language approach of only providing constructs to do things you can't do easily (even if not tersely) with other existing constructs.

Answer (score 3):

With `perl`

```bsh
perl -lne '$h{$_}++ if /Exception/;
           END{print "$_ $h{$_}" for sort {$h{$a} <=> $h{$b}} keys %h}'
```

`sort {$h{$a} <=> $h{$b}} keys %h` will sort based on hash value. See https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys for details.